# C# Simple Passing Parameters Issue

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I know I sound like a bad programmer right now - but I'm new and I can't figure out how to use this reference thing and pass parameters, I mean I know how to do it - but at the same time - this isn't working and I don't know why.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  DealCard(ref card);
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void DealCard(string card) {
  string finalNum = "";
  string finalSuite = "";
  bool diffCard = false;
  do {
    Random cardPicker = new Random();
    int cardSuite = cardPicker.Next(1, 5);
    if (cardSuite == 1) {
      finalSuite = "Hearts";
    } else if (cardSuite == 2) {
      finalSuite = "Spades";
    } else if (cardSuite == 3) {
      finalSuite = "Clubs";
    } else if (cardSuite == 4) {
      finalSuite = "Diamonds";
    }

    int cardNum = cardPicker.Next(1, 14);

    if (cardNum == 1) {
      finalNum = "Ace";
    } else if (cardNum == 2) {
      finalNum = "Two";
    } else if (cardNum == 3) {
      finalNum = "Thre";
    } else if (cardNum == 4) {
      finalNum = "Four";
    } else if (cardNum == 5) {
      finalNum = "Five";
    } else if (cardNum == 6) {
      finalNum = "Six";
    } else if (cardNum == 7) {
      finalNum = "Seven";
    } else if (cardNum == 8) {
      finalNum = "Eight";
    } else if (cardNum == 9) {
      finalNum = "Nine";
    } else if (cardNum == 10) {
      finalNum = "Ten";
    } else if (cardNum == 11) {
      finalNum = "Jack";
    } else if (cardNum == 12) {
      finalNum = "Queen";
    } else if (cardNum == 13) {
      finalNum = "King";
    }

    string newCard = finalNum + " of " + finalSuite;

    if (newCard != card) {
      card = finalNum + " of " + finalSuite;
      diffCard = true;
    } else {

    }
    card = newCard;

  } while (diffCard == false);
}
```

Yes I know that massive 'if' is an eyesore. 
Yes I know I could accomplish this in less than half the lines.
Yes I know it's a simple question.
Yes I know I'm bad, but I'd like to humbly request that anyone helps me to stop losing hair over this.

Comment: You do not need this: `DealCard(ref card);` because this will work: `DealCard(card);` However, if you intentionally want to use `ref` and you know exactly why, that is a different case.

Comment: I know you specifically asked for no losing head over the massive if. However, I only want to offer you simple & alternative solution: use dictionary. key would be number, value the string. Then you can replace the whole if just by cardValuesDict[cardNumber]

Comment: Declare `var card = "";` before calling `DealCard`.

Comment: Emphasizing on @aaron 's comment. have you declared card? anywhere??

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your method like this:

```
private static void DealCard(ref string card)
```

Basically the method has to accept a ref parameter.

Here is documentation to support the answer:

[Value Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters)

[Reference Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters)

Comment: I've already tried having 'ref' in the method along with 'string card' - and I've just put it in again now, still saying that 'The name 'card' does not exist in the current context' when I've tried to call it in the Main.

Comment: Can you post the full code?  Where is card declared?

Comment: Seems like your problem is not with ref.... It is with the declaration and scope of the card variable

Comment: so should I make another thread then asking for helping with the declaration and scope of the variable? And what I have posted is the full code

Comment: You need to declare your variable.  Card does not exist. The only reason you would need to use by ref is if you were going to use the variable after the call to DealCard.  You can also return the string from the method private static string DealCard(string card) and get the result from the call

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be like this

```
public class Program
{

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
  string card = "";
  DealCard(ref card);

}

private static void DealCard(ref string card) 
{
  string finalNum = "";
  string finalSuite = "";
  bool diffCard = false;
  do {
      Random cardPicker = new Random();
      int cardSuite = cardPicker.Next(1, 5);
      string[] suite =  new String[]{"Hearts","Spades", "Clubs", "Diaminds"};


      int cardNum = cardPicker.Next(1, 3);
      string[] numbers = new String[]{"one","two","three", "four"};



    string newCard = numbers[cardNum] + " of " + suite[cardSuite];

    if (newCard != card) {
      card = finalNum + " of " + finalSuite;
      diffCard = true;
    } else {

    }
    card = newCard;
      Console.WriteLine(newCard);


  } while (diffCard == false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that I'm afraid - it still says that 'card' doesn't exist in context during the main.

Comment: just a question. why do you want to use `ref`?

Comment: This answer is a duplicate answer. I answered the same thing 10 minutes ago

Comment: see updated answer ... it says card is not exist because you didn't initialize it